# PHP Regex get url segments

Tags: php, regex

can anybody please help?

i want to get the first two segments of a url
for example the url can look like this

```
/catalog/category-1
```

or

```
/catalog/category-1/filter/value
```

my current regex look like this...

```
/(\/catalog\/.*?)\//
```

This will work for the long url but not for the first example.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
$url = explode('/', trim($url, '/'));
$first_segment = $url[0];
$second_segment = $url[1];
```

Edit:
As pointed out by @Crisp in the comments, to prevent an empty first_segment, `trim` your string before you `explode` it.

Comment: I guess `$url[0]` will be an empty string, because of the leading slash.

Comment: `$url[0]` will be an empty string `""` with the url in the OP. Perhaps add `trim` or `ltrim`. eg `$url = explode('/', trim($url, '/'));`

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a regex to parse your URLs.  Use the built-in [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

After you get the path component from that function, you can use the [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to break apart the parts of the URL based on a slash.

```
<?php

$url = "http://example.com/this/that/other?page=1";

$parts = parse_url($url);

print 'Parts = ';
print_r($parts);

print 'Path = ' . $parts['path'] . "\n";

$path_components = explode( '/', $parts['path'] );
print "Path components = ";
print_r( $path_components );

?>
```

That gives you this:

```
Parts = Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => example.com
    [path] => /this/that/other
    [query] => page=1
)
Path = /this/that/other
Path components = Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => this
    [2] => that
    [3] => other
)
```

Comment: parse_url won't do the trick. All segments will be hold in `path`

Comment: i dont need thte parse_url function because i already have the path

Comment: @MatheusAzevedo How about `explode` on the path-part?

Comment: @eisberg Exactly my answer (:

Comment: **Never** use `split()` - despite its harmless name it's deprecated and uses posix regexps. If you want to split with a regex, use `preg_split`, otherwise use `explode`

Comment: @neowerk: Is there any reason for that besides "but i want!!!"? Regexps are NOT the preferred choice to split the path segments; they are fine to extract data from a single segment though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Already updated to use `explode` over `split`.  I didn't realize until I went to link to the manual page on php.net that it was deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex` is not the best tools in this case as others have pointed out but here it is using `regex`.

The problem with your `regex` is you are trying to match three `/`, use negation instead:

```
$str1='/catalog/category-1';
$str2='/catalog/category-1/filter/value';

preg_match('#/[^/]*/[^/]*#',$str1,$match);
echo $match[0].;

preg_match('#/[^/]*/[^/]*#',$str2,$match);
echo $match[0];
```

Output:

```
/catalog/category-1
/catalog/category-1
```

Explanation:

```
/      # Match first /
[^/]*  # Match anything not a /
/      # Match second /
[^/]*  # Match anything not a /
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the detailed explanation.
I'm not good at regex

Comment: You do NOT have to escape forward slashes when using `#` as the delimiter.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Ahh yes, I originally posted with `/` as the delimiter, updated now. @neowerk on stackoverflow the way to say thanks if by upvoting any useful answers and by accepting the most useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, use parse_url to split the url into host, port, path and query string.

Then, use this regex on the path :

```
<?php
preg_match('#^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)#i', $path, $matches);
?>
```